# conditional group matching using regex

Tags: c++, regex, perl, pcre, ecmascript-5

how to match a group except if it starts with a certain character.

e.g. I have the following sentence:

```
just _checking any _string.
```

I have the regex `([\w]+)` which matches all the words `{just, _checking, any, _sring}`. But, what I want is to match all the words that don't start with character `_` i.e. `{just, any}`.

The above example is a watered down version of what I'm actually trying to parse.

I'm parsing a code file, which contains string in the following format :

```
package1.class1<package2.class2 <? extends package3.class3> , package4.class4 <package5.package6.class5<?>.class6.class7<class8> >.class9.class10
```

The output that I require should create a match result like all the fully qualified names (having at least one `.` in the middle )but stop if encounter a `<`.

So, the result should be :

```
{ package1.class1, package2.class2, package3.class3, package4.class4, package5.package6.class5 }
```

I wrote `([\w]+\.)+([\w]+)` to parse it but it also matches `class6.class7` and `class9.class10` which I don't want. I know it's way off the mark and I apologize for that.

Hence, I earlier asked if I can ignore a capture group starting from a specific character.

Here's the link where I tried : [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/v1jfXC/3)

there everything that it is matching is correct except the part where it matches `class6.class7` and `class9.class10`.

I'm not sure how to proceed on this. I'm using C++14 and it supports ECMAScript grammar as well along with POSIX style.

**EDIT** : as suggested by @Corion, I've added more details.
**EDIT2** : added regex101 link

Comment: Why should `package5.package6.class5` be in the matched set, but not `class8`? I think your specification is misguided/unclear.

Comment: I've edited my answer.

Comment: ... edited again, so to also exclude `class8`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a word boundary `\b` and make sure that the first character is not an underscore (but still a letter):

```
(\b(?=[^_])[\w]+)
```

Using the following Perl script to validate that:

```
perl -wlne "print qq(Matched <$_>) for /(\b(?=[^_])[\w]+)/g"

Matched <just>
Matched <any>
```

[regex101 playground](https://regex101.com/r/msgPNh/1)

In response to the expansion of the question in the comment, the following regular expression will also capture dots in the "middle" of the word (but still disallow them at the start of a word):

```
(\b(?=[^_.])[\w.]+)

perl -wlne "print qq(Matched <$_>) for /(\b(?=[^_.])[\w.]+)/g"

just _checking any _string. and. this. inclu.ding dots
Matched <just>
Matched <any>
Matched <and.>
Matched <this.>
Matched <inclu.ding>
Matched <dots>
```

[regex101 playground](https://regex101.com/r/rszonH/1)

After the third expansion of the question, I've expanded the regular expression to match the class names but exclude the `extends` keyword, and only start a new match when there was a space (`\s`) or less-than sign (`<`). The full qualified matches are achieved by forcing a dot ( `\.` ) to appear in the match:

```
(?:^|[<>\s])(?:(?![_.]|\bextends\b)([\w]+\.[\w.]+))

perl -nwle "print qq(Matched <$_>) for /(?:^|[<>\s])(?:(?![_.]|\bextends\b)([\w]+\.[\w.]+))/g"

Matched <package1.class1>
Matched <package2.class2>
Matched <package3.class3>
Matched <package4.class4>
Matched <package5.package6.class5>
```

[regex 101 playground](https://regex101.com/r/rszonH/5)

Comment: you can replace `(?=[^_])` by `(?!_)`

Comment: @Corion : what if the symbol isn't there in `\w`, say, instead of `_` I want to exclude words starting with `.` but include if it doesn't start with `.` and comes only in the middle ?

Comment: @helix Can you maybe edit your post and specify your question in more detail then? This is likely mostly a matter of adding the relevant parts to the exclusion part (`(?=[^_.])`) and adding them to the latter inclusion part (`[\w.]+`).

Comment: Instead of Perl can just use [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/tFWYdS/1) for a quick test

Comment: @Corion: updated the question as you suggested. I believe the problem I was trying to solve was way off-track from what I asked and I apologize for that. Can you please take a look at the updated question?

Comment: @helix The first regex already does what your expanded question asks. It still captures `extends`. Do you want to exclude that?